# E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update error with Docker

Tags: docker

Tried to build the following docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update
...
```

with the following command:

```
sudo docker build -t ubuntu22 .
```

but got:

```
Fetched 22.0 MB in 2s (11.8 MB/s)
Reading package lists...
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I used `FROM ubuntu:21.10`
but build result

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
```

"Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) End of Life reached on July 14 2022".

Then I changed 21.10 to 22.04 and run build (after apt-get update)

```
Reading package lists...
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Edit: Then I changed previous LTS version (FROM ubuntu:20.04) and everything works

Comment: You did not post an answer, this should be a comment to the original question.

Comment: Same here, changed from ubuntu:latest to ubuntu:20.04 and it worked.